# Http Post envia los datos en desorden

Tags: javascript, angular, http-post

tengo una una función que envía datos que se encuentra en un vector con un http post, entonces lo que hago es recorrer el vector con un ciclo for y voy enviando los datos a la base de datos, el problema que tengo es que los datos están llegando en desorden a la base de datos, es decir, primero sube la posición 2 del vector, después la 4, y así, es decir se están subiendo de manera aleatoria. este es el código.

```
$scope.enviarlimites = function (){
    var nombreLimite = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var idMapa = document.getElementById('mapa_id').value;

    if($scope.numerodepuntos==0 || $scope.numerodepuntos==null || nombreLimite==null || nombreLimite==""){
        swal({
            title: "Error",
            text: "Debe ingresar todos los datos del mapa.",
            icon: "error"
        })
    }else{
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.numerodepuntos; i++){

            var latitudbd = $scope.vectorCoordenadas[i].lat;
            var longitudbd =  $scope.vectorCoordenadas[i].lng;
            var nombrelimitebd = nombreLimite+i;

            $http.post("/territoriosinteligentes/enviarlimites", {nombre: nombrelimitebd, latitud: latitudbd,
                longitud: longitudbd, identificador: nombreLimite, mapa_id: idMapa}).then(function(response)
            {

                $scope.status = response.status;
                $scope.data = response.data;
                swal({title: "Cargando Limites",text: "Por favor espere.",icon: "success"})

            },

            function(response) {
                $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
                $scope.status = response.status;
                swal({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: "No se pudo hacer el registro de los limites, debe ingresar todos los datos",
                    icon: "error"
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿seguro que llegan desordenados al servidor? ¿O quizás es la respuesta del servidor la que estás recibiendo en el cliente desordenada? Lo segundo no me extraña, debido a que aunque lances todas las peticiones casi a la vez, al ser asíncronas puedes recibir la respuesta en otro orden. Lo primero me parece un poco más raro, pero también podría ser. Si el orden es importante ¿por qué no envías una lista como JSON en lugar de iterar por ella?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, si llegan en desorden, creo que es porque las peticiones tardan diferentes tiempos y entonces se sube la que termina primero, y no siempre es en orden. no se como solucionar eso... cuando te refieres a enviar una lista como JSON a que te refieres? estoy aprendiendo sobre esto.

Comment: Me refiero a que, si tienes control sobre el _backend_ (es decir, si lo has programado tú), le añadas un _endpoint_ (una ruta) en la cual en lugar de esperar por un diccionario con los datos de un elemento, espere por una lista de diccionarios. Así el cliente le enviaría en un solo POST la lista completa y de ese modo te aseguras de que el orden es correcto. Aunque realmente no entiendo por qué el orden en que lleguen debería ser importante, ya que cada uno lleva su id.

Comment: Hola, si el problema es que al realizar un POST los tiempos son distintos, es decir, ejemplo: cuando recorro la primera posición del vector, se realiza un post y tiene un tiempo de duración de 80ms, luego la segunda posición al realizar el post tarda 20ms, por lo tanto el orden de subida se ve alterado, y primero se sube la posición dos antes que la numero uno, tienes alguna idea de como manejar este problema?

Comment: Hay muchas opciones, podrías enviar todo el arreglo en una sola llamada y procesarlo en el backend, o hacer llamadas recursivas esperando las respuestas de las anteriores, aunque esta última opción degradaria la performance, yo iría por enviar todo el vector y procesarlo en el backend

Comment: @ramirozap hola, como así lo de hacer llamadas recursivas?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más práctico sería enviar todo el vector de puntos en una sola llamada, con esto se simplifica bastante la lógica del frontend, y se le pasa la responsabilidad al backend, lo que haría la app más performante ya que no tienes `n` llamadas a la API, las llamadas son costosas, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías resolver la parte de front

```
$scope.enviarlimites = function (){
    var nombreLimite = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    var idMapa = document.getElementById('mapa_id').value;

    if($scope.numerodepuntos==0 || $scope.numerodepuntos==null || nombreLimite==null || nombreLimite==""){
        swal({
            title: "Error",
            text: "Debe ingresar todos los datos del mapa.",
            icon: "error"
        })
    }else{
        $http.post("/territoriosinteligentes/enviarlimites", { 
            puntos: $scope.vectorCoordenadas, 
            identificador: nombreLimite, 
            mapa_id: idMapa })
        .then(function(response) {
                $scope.status = response.status;
                $scope.data = response.data;
                swal({title: "Cargando Limites",text: "Por favor espere.",icon: "success"})
            },

            function(response) {
                $scope.data = response.data || 'Request failed';
                $scope.status = response.status;
                swal({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: "No se pudo hacer el registro de los limites, debe ingresar todos los datos",
                    icon: "error"
                })
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, y que tipo de dato en la base de datos seria "Puntos"

Comment: `puntos` es un vector, de hecho es una copia de `vectorCoordenadas`, en el backend tienes que fijarte como quieres tratarlo